# A general theory of pairings

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, modules, abelian-groups

Bilinear forms and bilinear maps for vector spaces over a field are standard material for an introductory course in linear algebra.

There are also text books for bilinear forms and related quadratic forms in the context of modules e.g. over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$, although there are still a lot of open problems.

Pairings arise in arithmetic geometry, e.g. for elliptic curves (e.g. [implemented in magma](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1507)) or the Brauer-Manin pairing in the theory of obstructions to local-global principles, where Brauer group elements are paired with elements of the group of zero cycles or with adelic points and the adelic points do not need to form a group.

I am interested in a reference to a general theory of pairings. In particular in the context of pairings between abelian groups (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$-modules), what is known about the relation between left kernels and right kernels?